# Unknown compiler option eslint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am using React and emotion/react.

to make some typing works with custom props, I need to add the following line to my `compilerOptions` in `tsconfig`

```
"jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
```

now eslint is complaining in all my imports that

> Parsing error: Unknown compiler option 'jsxImportSource'.eslint

how can I make this work?